Some further explanation of Alex Smola's 1998 implementation of support vector regression
I am currently going through, and trying to implement the pseudo-code in Alex Smola's 1998 paper on support vector regression, particularly the one on sequential minimal optimization. (Section 4.6.3, http://alex.smola.org/papers/1998/Smola98.pdf). I have several questions

How exactly does he mean for the bias term to be updated? (He gives a brief explanation in section 1.1.4, but I do not know whether we have to compute a bias term for each Lagrange multiplier in the current problem set, or whether we do so for each problem in the problem set).
In his implementation, there's no actual way for the Lagrange multipliers to be updated, or to move from 0, as the selection for the multipliers seem to always set them to 0 for a positive, small epsilon value.

I would like to know how to solve these problems, or further resources that would aid me in my task. If there any more details you would like to know about my implementation, please, do not hesitate to ask
